# Java - How to get the last day of the week of the month

Tags: java

Is it possible to get the last day of the last week for the current month.

For instance, I want to get 31st as the last day of Week 5 for the month of August and 3rd as the the last day of Week 1 for the month of September.

**Edit**:

I am using this week as an example.There are 2 months in this week so I need to generated 2 different weekly reports to represent each month. so first report will be 28th to 31st of August and the second report will be 1st to 3rd of September. Week starts on Sunday

Comment: Monday is the first day of the week, no?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: the first sentence was easy to understand. the second one not.

Comment: Try getting the 5th sunday date.

Comment: I think OP means: The last day of the week which is still in the requested month, hence the 31st of August which is Wednesday. @Tobb - in some countries, the first day of the week is Sunday.

Comment: Then "last day of the week" is not well defined. Also, week numbering is not well defined (if sunday is the 1st, is this the first week of the month?). In addition, the last day of week X in august differs from year to year.

Comment: @ArcticLord Not the same question. Here the calculation involves both months and weeks within these months, and it is not asking necessarily about the last day of the month - as OP said, he wants the answer for "Last day of week 1 of September".

Comment: You need to explain better. I don’t get how Saturday 3 September can be counted in the last week of that month. Once your requirements are clear, it’s probably not too hard using `GregorianCalendar` or some third party calendar class library.

Comment: I am using this week as an example.There are 2 months in this week so I need to generated 2 different weekly reports to represent each month. so first report will be 28th to 31st of August and the second report will be 1st to 3rd of September. Week starts on Sunday

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting. Getting first/last day-of-month or day-of-week has been handled many many times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Basil Bourque... I did check stack overflow.But if you read my question right, it is a bit more complex than just to get first/last day of the month or week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: after your clarification in the comments here’s a solution. Given a month it returns a list containing one or two dates: one date if the month ends on a Saturday and thus with a whole week; if not, both the last day of the month and the following Saturday, where the week ends.

```
public static final int lastDayOfWeek = Calendar.SATURDAY;

/** month is 1 through 12 for Jan through Dec */
public static List<Date> lastDayOfLastWeek(int year, int month) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // set to a day in the month in question; Calendar’s month is 0-based, so subtract 1
    cal.set(year, month - 1, 1);
    // set to last day of month
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    List<Date> result = new ArrayList<Date>(2);
    result.add(cal.getTime());
    // is this also the last day of the week?
    int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if (dayOfWeek != lastDayOfWeek) { // no
        // set to last day of week and add one more date to result
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, lastDayOfWeek - dayOfWeek);
        result.add(cal.getTime());
    }
    return result;
}
```

For example, for April 2016 it returns just Saturday 30 April. For August it returns Wed 31 Aug and Sat 3 Sep since these are the dates where the two periods end that you need to build reports for.

Answer (score 0):

The simple logic can be as follow.
1. try calculating the day at which the last day of the month occured.
(for  example say the last day of Aug was Tuesday).
2. Now add the number of days to make it sunday (last day of the week).
(say add 5 to make it sunday)

and voila ....5 is your answer.

make it dynamic by putting monday=1,tuesday=2 and so on....
Hope this logic is helpful,please post your other findings if you have found anything other than this.